# Infinite recomposition on LazyColumn items in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I've got simple `LazyColumn`:

```
LazyColumn {
    val lazySportEvents: LazyPagingItems<RecyclerItem> = stateValue.pagingItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    lazySportEvents.apply {
                when (loadState.refresh) {
                    is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                        itemsIndexed(
                                lazyPagingItems = lazySportEvents,
                                itemContent = { index, item ->
                                    when (item) {
                                            is SportEvent -> Text(item.name)
                                            is AdItem -> AndroidView(
                                                factory = { context ->
                                                    AdImageView(context).apply{
                                                        loadAdImage(item.id)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            )
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

When I scroll screen down, everything loads fine. But when I scroll up, I end up with `fun loadAdImage()` called. It means that recomposition for `AdItem` happened even if that is the very same item (values and reference) like before scrolling screen down! Why does recomposition even happen then? I would like to omit it, to not load the same ad image every time while scrolling.

Is it even possible to skip recomposition for lazy paging items?

Edit: I realised the recomposition for items was infinite and that caused aforementioned behavior.

Comment: That is the expected behavior of lazy column, it reuses the references of previous columns and set new items everytime it appears on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I changed

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()
```

to

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
```

for some `Boxes` in the composable layout, infinite recomposition in `LazyColumn` stopped.

Edit: while working on the fix I experienced some Gradle dependencies caching problems. Anyway, when the problem approached for the 2nd time - the solution was to... upgrade `compose.foundation` dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$1.2.0-alpha07"
```

Not sure which one helped.